# Adding a counter statement to print values every 1 minute

Tags: python

I am trying to run a small equation by incrementing one variable (t), but only print the results every 500th time. I am using a counter function and remainder to indicate when I have a whole integer for the value and then print. In this code, it doesn't print anything. If I set the counter to "counter= counter+ 5", it will run and increment x 5, but print every time. Can you see what is wrong? You can see I commented some stuff out I was trying. I think the solution is something like this but I can't figure it out!

```
t = 0
counter = 0
#mass rocket = 4390
#mass fuel at launch =
mass= 13000
v = 0
a = 0
d = 0
deltat=.001

#gd = gdisplay(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=4000, title='v vs. t', xtitle='t', ytitle='v',foreground=color.black, background=color.white, xmax=70, xmin=0, ymax=4000, ymin=0)
while (t<=65):
    t = t + deltat
    mass = 13000 - (130*t)
    v = v + ((1880*(130*deltat))/(mass))
    a = ((1880/(mass))*((130*deltat)/(deltat)))
    d = d + ((v*deltat)+((.5)*a*(deltat*deltat)))
    #counter += .001
    counter = counter + t
    #counter%5==0
    if counter %5 == 0:
        print (counter)
        print (t)
        print (v)
        #print a
        print (d)
```

I tried this and it does not run. No errors, it just doesn't do anything.

```
t = 0
counter = 0
#mass rocket = 4390
#mass fuel at launch =
mass= 13000
v = 0
a = 0
d = 0
deltat=.001

#gd = gdisplay(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=4000, title='v vs. t', xtitle='t', ytitle='v',foreground=color.black, background=color.white, xmax=70, xmin=0, ymax=4000, ymin=0)
while (t<=65):
    t = t + deltat
    mass = 13000 - (130*t)
    v = v + ((1880*(130*deltat))/(mass))
    a = ((1880/(mass))*((130*deltat)/(deltat)))
    d = d + ((v*deltat)+((.5)*a*(deltat*deltat)))
    #counter = counter + 5.0
    if t % 1.0 == 0:
        #print (counter)
        print (t)
        print (v)
        print (d)
```

Jeepers- sorry I'm so daft. I tired this and it just runs once:

```
t = 0
counter = 0
#mass rocket = 4390
#mass fuel at launch =
#mass= 13000
v = 0
a = 0
d = 0
deltat=.001

#gd = gdisplay(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=4000, title='v vs. t', xtitle='t', ytitle='v',foreground=color.black, background=color.white, xmax=70, xmin=0, ymax=4000, ymin=0)
while (t<=65):
    t = t + deltat
    mass = 13000 - (130*t)
    v = v + ((1880*(130*deltat))/(mass))
    a = ((1880/(mass))*((130*deltat)/(deltat)))
    d = d + ((v*deltat)+((.5)*a*(deltat*deltat)))
    #counter += 1
    if counter % 500 == 0:
        print (counter)
        print(t)
        print(v)
        print(d)
        counter += 1
```

If I increment the counter above the if statement, it's incrementing t by .5s and not .001, and incrementing count x 500. I'm confused.

```
t = 0
counter = 0
#mass rocket = 4390
#mass fuel at launch =
#mass= 13000
v = 0
a = 0
d = 0
deltat=.001

#gd = gdisplay(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=4000, title='v vs. t', xtitle='t', ytitle='v',foreground=color.black, background=color.white, xmax=70, xmin=0, ymax=4000, ymin=0)
while (t<=65):
    t = t + deltat
    mass = 13000 - (130*t)
    v = v + ((1880*(130*deltat))/(mass))
    a = ((1880/(mass))*((130*deltat)/(deltat)))
    d = d + ((v*deltat)+((.5)*a*(deltat*deltat)))
    counter += 1
    if counter % 500 == 0:
        print (counter)
        print(t)
        print(v)
        print(d)
```

Comment: By the way, if you are using Python 3, `print` is a function so there shouldn't be a space between `print` and the parentheses. Another thing: you define `mass` as 13000 but then hard-code 1300 in the beginning of your loop.

Comment: Isn't this what you wanted? Your loop will enter your if statement every 500 iterations. Every 500 iterations, your t variable has increased 500 * 0.001 = 0.500.

Comment: Yes- you are correct and i think it's working. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

increment counter as such:

```
counter += 1
```

and print like this

```
if counter % 500 == 0:
    print (counter)
```

Comment: I just updated my question- but let me try your suggestion- thanks!

Comment: In your case, do I need to define "time" or import it? I'm novice just trying to learn this. I just want a simple function that says in english "If "t" is an integer value in multiples of x, then print the results." Here is sample output, but it should only print every 500th time for example.

Comment: 5.0
0.001
0.01880018800188002
2.820028200282003e-05
10.0
0.002
0.03760056400940017
7.520103401598027e-05

Comment: updated my answer. When Python increments t, there is a floating point error and isn't exactly 37.0 for example, but 37.00000000000447. So use the counter as shown above.

Comment: In response to your changed question, put "counter += 1" above your if statement. You are only incrementing counter when "counter = 0" then counter gets a value of 1. Then it never enters the if statement to change ever again... as to why it only prints once.

Comment: NVM- I think i got this figured out. Thank you so very much for your help. I was thinking actual time, and not processing loops.